# Erro de compilação quando adiciono "using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;"

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

quando adiciono o using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

"não é possível iniciar a depuração porque o destino de depuração 'c:\users\usuario\documents\visualstudio2018\Projects\Application\bin\Debug\Application.exe' está ausente. Construa o projeto e tente novamente, ou ajuste as propriedades OutputhPath e AssemblyName apropriadamente para apontar para uma localização correta do assembly de destino"

pode ser problema do sql com o firewall? como resolver?

Comment: Você instalou o pacote pelo nuget?

Comment: Não, eu adicionei referência, foi como eu fiz no ultimo projeto e deu certo. Mas agora instalei pelo nuget e deu certo, muito Obrigado ^^ (obs: como eu avalio a sua resposta?)